# Grunt uglify updating only function

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I am learning grunt and I started with grunt uglify. It worked first time and uglify my JavaScript but now it is only updating the function name not it's content. It looks like it is just updating the file content from cache. I am saying function name because I tried to change it to test it. Bellow is my gruntfile

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.initConfig({

uglify : {
  my_target : {
   files: {
    'js/script.js': ['component/js/*.js']
  }

}

}// uglify
,
 watch : {
   files:['component/js/*.js'],
   tasks:['uglify'],
   options: {
   spawn: false,
  }

  }//watch

 });

grunt.registerTask('default','watch');
}
```

I will appreciated any help regarding it.

Comment: Never happened to me and also no same thing on internet. Have you tried to remove the output js file and run the task again??

Comment: Yes I have tried it but same result. It's a pretty weird bug and yeah right couldn't found on the internet too.